# How can i always setState when the page is opened?

Tags: flutter, dart, state

My issue is, when the page is opened my variable isn't set. So when i'm querying from firestore i get the error `The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("userbio")`

I declared 2 variables

```
  var userid;
  var useremail;
```

Then i wrote this future

```
Future getUserData() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final String uid = user.uid.toString();
    final String email = user.email.toString();
    DocumentReference qn = await firestore
        .collection("users")
        .document(email)
        .collection('userdetails')
        .document(uid);
    void initState() {
      setState(() {
        userid = uid;
        useremail = email;
      });
    }

   
    return qn.documentID;
  }
```

This is how i'm currently trying to setState but it's not working

```
void initState() {
          setState(() {
            userid = uid;
            useremail = email;
          });
        }
```

Please help, thanks.
comment if you need more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're declaring the nested function `initState()` but you're not calling it. I would just remove the function and call `setState()` directly :

```
...
.document(uid);
setState(() {
...
```

EDIT : Call `getUserData()` inside `initState` :

```
// In a class extending State<T>
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // synchronous call if you don't care about the result
    getUserData();
    // anonymous function if you want the result
    () async {
        var result = await getUserData();
    }();
}
```

*PS : `initState()`, like `build()` or `setState()`, is a predefined name in Flutter. Try not to use those names for functions that are not overriding the original ones.*

Comment: I did this before i put it in an InitState, There's no difference. Same error

Comment: Then I don't understand. Maybe the collection/document call is failing. You can try moving the `setState()` before it.

Comment: Hmm, when i print the value 'useremail' it says its null. Meaning the state was never set. Right?

Comment: Also, the error hasn't changed. its still `The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("userbio")`

Comment: All i'm trying to do is: (1.) Create a variable  (2.) get the current userid (3.) set the variable as the current userid

Comment: okay so, i've just created a button and when this is pressed it calls on the future. when that happens the state is set and everything works. The task now is how to do that automatically. how to eradicate having to press on the button

Comment: Ok, so you can do that by calling `getUserData()` inside `initState()`. I'm gonna edit my answer to provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try assign your variable an empty value instead of leaving it null.

```
var userid = '';
var useremail = '';
```